# Dynamic variables in perl

Tags: perl, special-variables

I am wondering about how I can do in Perl what I commonly do in lisp:

```
(defvar *verbose-level* 0)
(defun my-function (... &key ((:verbose-level *verbose-level*) *verbose-level*) ...) ...)
```

this means that `my-function` is run at the current level of verbosity, but I can pass it a different level which will affect all its calls too:

```
(defun f1 (&key ((:verbose-level *verbose-level*) *verbose-level*))
  (format t "~S: ~S=~S~%" 'f1 '*verbose-level* *verbose-level*)
  (f2 :verbose-level 1)
  (format t "~S: ~S=~S~%" 'f1 '*verbose-level* *verbose-level*)
  (f2 :verbose-level (1+ *verbose-level*))
  (format t "~S: ~S=~S~%" 'f1 '*verbose-level* *verbose-level*))
(defun f2 (&key ((:verbose-level *verbose-level*) *verbose-level*))
  (format t "~S: ~S=~S~%" 'f2 '*verbose-level* *verbose-level*))
[17]> (f1)
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=0
F2: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=1
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=0
F2: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=1
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=0
NIL
[18]> (f1 :verbose-level 4)
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=4
F2: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=1
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=4
F2: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=5
F1: *VERBOSE-LEVEL*=4
```

(note that the variable bindings are restored on exit - even abnormal - from functions).

How can I do something like that in Perl?

E.g., in `misc.pm`, I have `our $verbose=0;`.
How do I write a function which would bind `$verbose` to a value of its argument and restore its value on return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl's concept of global variables is quite similar to special variables in CL.

You can “shadow” the value of a global variable with `local`:

```
our $var = 1;

func("before");

{
  # a block creates a new scope
  local $var = 2;
  func("inside");
}

func("after");

sub func { say "@_: $var" }
```

Output:

```
before: 1
inside: 2
after: 1
```

If you `local` a value, the new value is visible throughout the whole dynamic scope, i.e. in all functions that are called. The old value is restored once the lexical scope is left by any means (errors, returns, etc). Tail calls do not extend the dynamic scope, but count as scope exit.

Note that global variables have a fully qualified name. From a different package, you would do something like

```
local $Other::Package::var = 3;
Other::Package::func("from a package far, far away");
```

This is commonly used to provide configuration for packages with a functional (non-OO) interface. Important examples are
  [`Carp`](https://metacpan.org/module/ZEFRAM/Carp-1.26/lib/Carp.pm)
and
  [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper).

Comment: It is kind of funny to see the similarities between Perl and CL. Starting with the compilation model (why *shouldn't* code be executed during parsing?) over special vs. lexical vars up to seperate namespaces (CL: variables, functions, labels, streams, …; Perl: scalars, arrays, hashes, subs, IO, …). Oh, and CLOS/Moose are obviously related

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you need to locally override a global variable inside a function.

```
package my_package;
our $verbose = 0;

sub function {
    my ($arg1, $arg2) = @_; # getting function arguments.
    local $verbose = $arg1;
}
```

It will restore old state of `$verbose` on return.

Comment: Thanks. What if `function` is called without arguments? I.e., `$arg1` is unbound. Do I need to resort to `local $verbose = defined $arg1 ? $arg1 : $verbose` or is there a prettier approach?

Comment: You can write `local $verbose = $arg1 if defined $arg1;`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If `$arg1` is not defined, then `$verbose` will be undefined. What you can do is `local $verbose = shift; $verbose = "default" if not defined $verbose;` (Or use the defined-or assignment operator: `$verbose //= "default"`).

Comment: Well, it does make sense - I checked it in a script. `$verbose` will be overridden locally only if `$arg1` is defined. Otherwise the `local $versbose = $arg1` isn't executed at all.